# Numpy NaN format in array not considered null

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I am trying to populate a dataframe with the following code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.choice([1, np.nan], size=5))


0     1  
1     1  
2   NaN  
3     1  
4     1
```

Then:

```
df[df[0].isnull()]

2   NaN
```

So far, so good. But if I am modifying the 1 to '1' things get strange (imo).

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.choice(['1', np.nan], size=5))

0    1  
1    1  
2    1  
3    1  
4  nan
```

Problems come with the isnull

```
df[df[0].isnull()]

Empty DataFrame  
Columns: [0]  
Index: []
```

How can I get the nan (which is a string) to behave like a NaN? 
I want to be able to filter quickly on all null/non-null values within my dataframe.

Thanks.

Comment: The issue here is that the `NaN` is being converted to the `str` `nan` which is surprising AFAIK real `NaN` require `float` `dtype`, in this case you'd have to compare with the str `nan` which is weird IMO

Comment: Thanks. For the moment I am converting the `str` `nan` back to the "normal" `NaN` .

Comment: I kinda feel this is a bug though as I wouldn't expect 'nan' when I've explicitly passed `NaN`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NaN` is a concept which makes sense while working with numbers, not strings. When you create the dataframe with `'1'`s Pandas is inferring the type of that column: `str`, which IMO is correct. So it will then convert `NaN` values to their string representation.

Note that if, for example, you say:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.choice(['1', 2], size=5))
```

The `2` will be converted as well to strings. Because, again, Pandas is inferring the string type for the whole column.

However, you can still filter easily with your proposed dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.choice(['1', np.nan], size=5))
df[df[0] == 'nan']
```

Comment: I spot the automatic conversion, but it's not happening when using None.  `pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.choice(['1', None], size=5))` will generate a dataframe with some NoneType value in it.

Comment: Actually, playing with this, `None` is working with the `isnull` method.

Comment: @Extratoro: Interesting. Note that `None` is a different type; a basic Python type, which Pandas may be treating differently. However, `NaN` is a `float` type; see `type(numpy.nan)`. So I guess Pandas will simply convert any number (int or float) to string when it infers the `str` type for the column (and `NaN` is simply a `float` type).